# How to make a custom QStyledItemDelegate selectable in a QListView in PySide/PyQt?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyside

As a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33371298/how-to-make-subclass-of-qstyleditemdelegate-react-properly-on-mouse-hover-in-a-q/33380476?noredirect=1#comment54638813_33380476), which was solved, I now want to make the items **selectable**. As mentioned earlier, I activated all kinds of selection-related parameters in the view and I also return `core.Qt.ItemIsSelectable` in the `flags`-method of the model. But still `option.state & gui.QStyle.State_Selected` is never fullfilled. Any help is highly appreciated. Please also note the minimal example in the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it myself. The problem was, that the custom QStyledItemDelegate catches the mouse event, so that it is not passed to the QListView. So in the `QStyledItemDelegate.editor(Event)` one simply needs to add

```
if event.type() == core.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
    return False
```

Now the selection is detectable in the `paint()`-method using `option.state & gui.QStyle.State_Selected`.

Comment: FYI, I think the more pythonic model for this would be to explicitly return `True` on the cases you are handling, and then `return QStyledItemDelegate.editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index)` which will call the base implementation of the method. Pretty sure that will give the same behaviour (but could be wrong!)